# Roll summing over a long stretch

Tags: probability, dice, expectation

Say I roll a 6-sided die until its sum exceeds $X$. What is E(rolls)?

Comment: There was a similar question posted yesterday (or so), apparently deleted. THe answer is surely not trivial. Are you interested on asymptotics, approximations or numerical methods? Here's an analogous question, only with continuos variables: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/141942/what-is-the-expected-number-of-random-numbers-generated-uniformly-such-that-th

Comment: This is an interesting question.  The answer can't be $X/3.5$ because if $X=0.5$ the expected number of rolls is 1.  It's obviously a nondecreasing function of $X$.  Does anyone know if generating functions would help here?

Answer (score 2):

Let $h(s)$ be the expected number of rolls to exceed $X$, starting with a sum of $s$. 
Then "first step analysis" gives the recursive formula $h(s)=1+{1\over 6}\sum_{j=1}^6 h(s+j)$ for $0\leq s\leq X$, while $h(s)=0$ for $s>X$. You use this equation to calculate $h(s)$ for  $s=X,X-1,X-2,\dots$ and eventually work your way back to $h(0)$, the answer to your question.

The answer $h(0)$ will be very close to $X/3.5$ for large $X$.

Comment: I wonder... doesn't that recursive formula assume that the die value that happens to "cross" the value X is equally distributed in 1..6 ? That would be a wrong assumption.

Comment: @leonbloy It does not make that false assumption.

Comment: @user2777137 Sorry I don't know of any faster way to calculate this.

Answer (score 2):

One looks for $n(x+1)$ where, for every integer $k$, $n(k)$ denotes the expected number of rolls needed to exceed $x$ starting from $x+1-k$. Thus, $n(k)=1+\frac16\sum\limits_{i=1}^6n(k-i)$ for every $k\geqslant1$ and $n(k)=0$ for every $k\leqslant0$.

For every $|s|\lt1$, let $N(s)=\sum\limits_{k}n(k)s^k$, then the one-step recursion above yields
$$
N(s)=\sum\limits_{k\geqslant1}s^k+\frac16\sum\limits_{i=1}^6s^i\sum\limits_{k\geqslant1}n(k)s^k,
$$
that is,
$$
N(s)=\frac{\frac{s}{1-s}}{1-\frac16\sum\limits_{i=1}^6s^i}=\frac{6s}{(1-s)^2Q(s)},
$$
where
$$
Q(s)=6+5s+4s^2+3s^3+2s^4+s^5.
$$
This shows that $n(x+1)\sim\nu x$ when $x\to\infty$, with
$$
\nu=\lim_{s\to1}(1-s)^2N(s)=\frac6{Q(1)}=\frac27.
$$
To go further, consider $\bar n(k)=n(k)-\nu k$ and $\bar N(s)=\sum\limits_{k\geqslant1}\bar n(k)s^k$, then
$$
(1-s)\bar N(s)=\frac{6s}{Q(s)Q(1)}\,\frac{Q(1)-Q(s)}{1-s}\to\mu,\qquad \mu=\frac{6Q'(1)}{Q(1)^2},
$$
hence $\bar n(k)\to\mu$ with $\mu=10/21$. Finally,
$$
n(x+1)=\frac27(x+1)+\frac{10}{21}+o(1),
$$
where $o(1)$ is geometrically small when $x\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L(x)$ be the expected number of rolls to reach $x$.  Clearly $L(x)=0$ for $x\le 0$, and for $x\ge 1$ the expected number is one more than the expected number remaining after the next roll.  That is,
$$
L(x)=I_{+}(x) + \frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^{6}L(x-k),
$$
where $I_{+}(x)$ is $1$ for positive $x$ and zero otherwise.  Now consider the [Z-transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform) of $L(x)$, defined by $\tilde{L}(z)=\sum_{x}L(x)z^{-x}$.  Multiplying both sides of the previous equation by $z^{-x}$ and summing over $x$ gives
$$
\tilde{L}(z)=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}z^{-x}+\tilde{L}(z)\left(\frac{1}{6}\sum_{k=1}^{6}z^{-k}\right)=\frac{1}{z-1}+\frac{z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1}{6z^6}\tilde{L}(z),
$$
or
$$
\tilde{L}(z)=\frac{6z^6}{6z^7-7z^6+1}.
$$
The inverse Z-transform is then
$$
L(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\tilde{L}(z)z^{x-1}dz,
$$
or the sum of the residues of ${6z^6}/(6z^7-7z^6+1)$.  It turns out that $\tilde{L}(z)$ has a second-order pole at $z=1$ and simple poles at five other locations:
$$
\tilde{L}(z)= \frac{\frac{2}{7} + \frac{16}{21}(z-1)}{(z-1)^2} + \sum_{j=1}^{5}\frac{R_{j}}{z-\omega_j},
$$
where $R_j$ are the residues and $\omega_j$ are the locations of the respective poles (the largest $|\omega_j|$ is about $0.73$, and the residues are $0.1$ or so).  The result is then
$$
L(x)=\frac{2}{7}x + \frac{10}{21} + \sum_{j=1}^{5}R_{j}\omega_j^{x-1}.
$$
The corrections to the leading (linear and constant) terms are exponentially decaying with $x$; for $x=10$, they sum to about $-0.01$.

Comment: Very confused how you calculate R and w

Comment: Well, you can ask WolframAlpha for "residues of $6z^6/(6z^7-7z^6+1)$", for one approach.  Generally you need to do this numerically, unless the denominator happens to have rational roots.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a random variable with discrete uniform distribution in $[1, 6]$, and let n be a number. If m is the number of trials needed to exceed n, we can conclude:

-sum of m trials is more than n.

-sum of m-1 trial is less than n.

So the question is: Let $Y_n$ be a sum of n independent variables with distribution as $X$. What is the probability of $Y_n<r$ for any r given?

I assume it can be solved, but the solution might involve scary integrals I doesn't like. Maybe someone else can continue from here.