# How many dice to total $50$ or more?

Tags: probability

I figure that the expected value of a dice is $3.5$, and so I expect on average that I will need to throw the dice $15$ times in order for the cumulative total to equal or exceed $50$, $14\cdot3.5$ being $49$ and $15\cdot3.5=52.5$.

Is this reasoning correct? I am wondering how I can phrase the question so that the answer is correctly an integer.

Comment: It is correct that you'd need to throw the dice $15$ times for the expected value of the cumulative total to be above $50$; however, if you throw the die $9$ times and get a $6$ every time, you'd have a cumulative total of $54$ with only $9$ throws.  What is it that you're asking?

Comment: Yes, it is. You have the expected value for throwing 15 fair dice of six sides. But this number maybe more or less significant due to variance.

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Are you asking how many throws are needed, in average, to make the sum of the outcomes $\geq 50$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I think I've covered all the options in myanswer. We'll see :-).

Comment: You can calculate the exact value using my answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550441/roll-summing-over-a-long-stretch/550480#550480  In your problem, the answer turns out to be ${1988628542275798220142492459445043894983\over 134713546244127343440523266742756048896}\approx 14.7619$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question as expanded in the text is not totally clear but as asked in the subject line, the reasoning is wrong.

> How many dice to total $50$ or more?

(1) The number of 'fair' dice with outcomes $1\dots6$
that must be thrown to POSSIBLY give $50$ or more is:

$N \ge \dfrac{50}{\text{maximum_throw}}$

$ \ge 50/6 = 8.333 \to 9$ dice.

(2) The number of 'fair' dice with outcomes $1\dots6$
that must be thrown to ALWAYS give $50$ or more is:

$N \ge \dfrac{50}{\text{minimum_throw}}$

$\ge 50 /1 = 50 \to 50$ dice.
(You knew that).

(3) The expanded question in the text seems to be

> How many dice to total $50$ or more on average over many throws?

The number of 'fair' dice with outcomes $1\dots6$ that must be thrown to average a sum of $50$ or more over many throws is:

$N \ge \dfrac{50}{\text{mean of all outcomes}}$

$ \ge 50 /3.5  = 14.29 \to 15$ dice.

$15$ dice can be expected to give an average sum which varies around a mean of $15 \times 3.5 = 52.5$ over a large number of throws, but this will vary randomly about the mean.